# Passing parameters to function that creates a google map doesn't work

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm assuming this is straight forward, just not having any luck with it.

I have the following functions

```
function init(myPoint) {
  var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(myPoint, -122.39031314844),
  zoom: 8,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
}

function start() {
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init(37.2342));
}
```

If I remove the param and just hardcode myPoint everything works. However in its current state it does not work. Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: EXACTLY the problem I was having!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your function is not called on window load; it is called upon code execution. instead of `init(37.2342)` you should use `function(){init(37.2342);}` with `addDomListener`:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () { init(37.2342); });
```

Comment: Can you explain the difference?